# How to implement recommendation system in an android application?

Tags: android, recommendation-engine

So, I have developed an android application based on a Youtube tutorial and now I was planning on implementing a recommendation system. It's a food delivery application that I developed and I wanted to know how can I integrate a recommendation system into the app so that people can get suggestion on food items. I used Firebase to store and retrieve data but I am not sure how I can use recommendation system so that it can retrieve data from firebase and suggest customers on what to choose? I am beginner in developing and writing algorithms. Any help would really be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hy Cries,

I had implemented recommendation system in my final year project.
The thing is first of all you should go through some of the patent papers which are published on your kind of recommendation system that you want to implement(Eg.YouTube).

As in you app you should do recommendation for new user as "Popularity recommendation" (type of rec.)and for old user "User-User recommendation".

User - User is the simplest one but for other type for recommendation you have to integrate python code which will run on jdoodle server and return result in form of string and use it as your output.

Feel free to ask anything related to this!
I hope you got something from this.

Comment: HI Harsh, I was kind of hoping to implement something similar. I did do my research on google regarding the api's but wasn't able to find one. Do you know any kind of API that I can use to implement recommendation model?